# Geek squad says my hard drive is failing?

Tags: windows-vista

I have an older laptop, dell duo core 2.1ghz, 6gb ram, 500gb hd. It is running vista. Was working fine although maybe a tad slower than when new when all of a sudden some things stopped working, seems like mostly internet. Examples some pages are not loading or very slow, or load but without any pictures, most videos don't stream etc.. touchpad zoom doesn't work anymore..
I am definitely low-tech but I tried to run things like disk defragmenter and other performance test and everything seems fine so I'm not sure what the problem is or how to troubleshoot so I can at least confirm what the problem is.
Any help? Where to look, what to do?

Comment: spinrite by grc from grc.com or mhdd will do a complete in depth surface scan.  However, its time to upgrade, buy a 512GB ssd and it will be worth every penny.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Vista is outdated and prone to bugs... I'd recommended a new(er) laptop or Operating System. That being said...

You can use some tools like CrystalDisk, Speccy, HWinfo, to check the SMART status of the hard drive. This will only tell you if the Smart Status has failed. The next test if they say the SMART status is fine would be to use a tool to scan the hard drive for bad Sectors. You might still be able to use HDTune, (though I think it's discontinued now-a-days).

The way it normally appears to me
-Constant errors at the same point (accessing a certain program, certain features failing etc...) can indicate a bad Hard drive.
-Random errors (programs randomly work, randomly the computer crashes) generally lead me to think motherboard or Ram as being faulty.

Comment: "Constant errors at the same point (accessing a certain program, certain features failing etc...) can indicate a bad Hard drive" - not necessarily - if the fault is where the page file is located all sorts of strange errors can result ...